# XML/XSL: How to output the price depending on what 'productId' is associated with the customer?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XML and XSL and I'm trying to output the price of an item depending on `itemcode` that the customer bought. I am doing a XML to XML code

XML Code:

```
<root>
    <orders>
        <order>
            <id> 1 </id>
            <customer> Cinderella </customer>
            <address> Makati </address>
        </order>
        
        <order>
            <id> 2 </id>
            <customer> Belle </customer>
            <address> Manila </address>
        </order>
        
        <order>
            <id> 3 </id>
            <customer> Shrek </customer>
            <address> Cebu </address>
        </order>
    </orders>
    
    
    <items>
        <item>
            <orderId> 2 </orderId>
            <name> Apple </name>
            <qty> 3 </qty>
            <productId> 1 </productId>
        </item>
        
        <item>
            <orderId> 2 </orderId>
            <name> Mango </name>
            <qty> 2  </qty>
            <productId> 2 </productId>
        </item>
        
        <item>
            <orderId> 1 </orderId>
            <name> Melon </name>
            <qty> 1  </qty>
            <productId> 3 </productId>
        </item>
        
        <item>
            <orderId> 3 </orderId>
            <name> Melon </name>
            <qty> 2  </qty>
            <productId> 3 </productId>
        </item>
        
        <item>
            <orderId> 3 </orderId>
            <name> Apple </name>
            <qty> 3  </qty>
            <productId> 1 </productId>
        </item>
    </items>
    
    
    <products>
        <product>
            <itemid> 1 </itemid>
            <name> Apple </name>
            <price> 30.00 </price>
        </product>
        
        <product>
            <itemid> 2 </itemid>
            <name> Mango </name>
            <price> 20.00 </price>
        </product>
        
        <product>
            <itemid> 3 </itemid>
            <name> Melon </name>
            <price> 50.00 </price>
        </product>
    </products>
    
    
</root>
```

XSL Code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <!-- TODO customize transformation rules 
         syntax recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt 
    -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <invoices>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/orders/order">
                <xsl:variable name="id" select="id"/>
                <xsl:variable name="prodId" select="productId"/>
                <invoice>
                    <customer>
                        <xsl:value-of select="customer/text()"/>
                    </customer>
                    
                    <city>
                        <xsl:value-of select="address/text()"/>
                    </city>
                    
                    <items>
                        <xsl:for-each select="../../items/item[orderId=$id]">

                            <item>
                                <name>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                </name>
                                
                                <quantity>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="qty"/>
                                </quantity>
                                
                                <price>
                                    <xsl:if test="itemId=$prodId">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="../../products/product/price"/>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </price>
                        
                                
                            </item> 
                            
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </items>
                  
                </invoice>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </invoices>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output should via XML also:

Price should depend on what the customer bought based on the `itemid` (E.g. if Melon price = 30.00. If Apple price = 20.00, etc)

Example output:

```
<invoices>
 <invoice>
   <customer>Cinderella</customer> 
   <city>Makati</city> 
    <items>
      <item>
        <name>Melon</name> 
        <quantity>1</quantity> 
        <price>30.00</price> 
      </item>
    </items>
  </invoice>
<invoice>
```

Comment: Why did you vandalize your question?

Answer (score 1):

XSLT has a built-in [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references; I strongly recommend you use it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item" match="item" use="orderId" />
<xsl:key name="product" match="product" use="itemid" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <invoices>
        <xsl:for-each select="orders/order">
            <invoice>
                <xsl:copy-of select="customer"/>
                <city>
                    <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
                </city>
                <items>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('item', id)">
                        <item>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
                            <quantity>
                                <xsl:value-of select="qty"/>
                            </quantity>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="key('product', productId)/price"/>
                        </item> 
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </items>
            </invoice>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </invoices>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```